# Libgdx deprecated drawMultiLine and getBounds

Tags: android, libgdx, bitmap-fonts

So i found a toolkit to create VisualNovels but it uses

```
        font.drawMultiLine(
               batch,
               previous.toString() + current.substring(0, c),
               dx, dy);
```

And

```
  else if (font.getBounds(test + words[i] + " ").width <= LINE_LENGTH) {
            if (i == (total - 1)){
                line.append(words[i]);
                linesArray.add(line.toString());
                lines++;
            }else
                line.append(words[i] + " ");
           }else if (font.getBounds(test + words[i] + " ").width > LINE_LENGTH){
                linesArray.add(test);
                line.replace(0, line.length(), words[i] + " ");
                lines++;
```

I'm Kinda new to Java and I don't know how to change all that code into what the wiki says:

http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3658

It says that i should replace getBounds with Glyph but getBounds is not commented and I'm not sure what it does

Comment: By the way this is the toolkit:https://github.com/0xCA2/Visual-Novel-Toolkit/blob/master/core/src/com/oxca2/cyoat/AnimatedText.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the deprecation instructions, instead of

```
font.getBounds(myText).width
```

you should use:

```
new GlyphLayout(font, myText).width
```

(This is just a pointer; you should optimize it and not create new objects every time)